# display <select> as a inline-block

Tags: html, select, listbox

I have a `<select>` element defined like this:

```
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
```

I would like to get the same functionality (being able to select an option), except I want to permanently display all the options, instead of hiding them in a drop-down-list. I basically want to make a listbox.

- Would this be possible?
- Is there already an element that will do this?
- Would I have to modify the  element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **size** attribute in your **select** widget

code

```
<select name="file_type" size="8">
    <option value=".jpg">.JPG</option>
    <option value=".png">.PNG</option>
    <option value=".gif">.GIF</option>
</select>
```